# Watir webdriver: dynamically filling in form according to observed validation rules

Tags: ruby, forms, validation, watir-webdriver

I have a web form in which the fields often change.  The fields can have any number of validations, such as requiring numbers rather than text or requiring user to select an option from a list of check boxes.

Is there a simple way for Watir webdriver to complete the fields according to validation rules?  My hope is that there is a simpler way to complete the form than recoding the test script whenever the form changes.

Comment: Your next question isn't going to be about how to defeat captchas is it?

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to violate the purpose ofusing Watir.

Generally you use Watir to test the validations which you put in place as well as the general functionality of your system. Short cutting the validations would mean that one of the main reasons to use Watir was gone.

If you are looking to merely test controllers and models, then you can use unit testing instead of a front-end test.

Here is some info on how to test your models and controllers:
[A Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)